# ListView Accessory item display issue

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I am using a simple procedure to update listview items (DynamicAppearance), but have a problem.
I need that listview item (TAccessoryObjectAppearance, AccessoryType: Checkmark) will be shown(checked)/or not at runtime depending on the provided value.
It should be:

[image]

But I get:

[image]

At design time I set the Item as "not visible".

Here is the code which does not work:

```
procedure UpdateList(lv: TListView);
var
  Litem: TListViewItem;
  iName: TListItemText;
  iCheck: TListItemAccessory;
begin
  FDQuery.Open('SELECT Name, Value FROM tbl_values');

  lv.Items.Clear;
  lv.BeginUpdate;

  while not FDQuery.Eof do
  begin
    Litem := lv.Items.Add;

    iName      := Litem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Name');
    iName.Text := FDQuery.FieldValues['Name'];

    iCheck     := LItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemAccessory>('Check');
    if FDQuery.FieldValues['Value'] > 0 then
      iCheck.Visible:= True
    else
      iCheck.Visible := False;

    FDQuery.Next;
  end;

  lv.EndUpdate;
end;
```

This procedure runs on form.show event.

But then I run another procedure which changes some values in the database table and runs the same procedure (UpdateList) again to update listview item values. And now Checkmarks are showed correctly:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Delphi 10.2.1

Comment: What does it mean, when you say it *does not work*? How can we reproduce the problem? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the post with pictures.

Comment: Thanks, but you could have explained the actual problem in one sentence. Still you did not answer the question: **How can we reproduce the problem?** You need to provide the MCVE I requested. There's no point in people spending time and effort to guess **your** setup, trying to recreate **your** problem. Did you step through the code in the debugger, to verify actual database data?

Comment: In debugging what value does 'FDQuery.FieldValues' hold on initial start up?

Comment: Without a [MCVE] (and insight into the data the FDQuery pulls), it is difficult to root cause your issue, but you can use the following code snips to set/remove the checkmark:

To set the checkmark:

    Litem.ItemData.Accessory:=TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aCheckmark;

Uncheck an item by using this code:

    LItem.ItemData.Accessory:=TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aNone;

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems an issue related to the refresh of the tListVew.
I solved with a workaround using a timer (200ms) to fill the tListView after the show event of the form

Comment: I have the same Issue

Answer (score 1):

There is many issues with application of style lookups in delphi FMX controls. Most common issue is that just after the creation in code of a FMX styled object, its style data is not yet loaded as it is needed only when the object is rendered. So for short, the object must have its view initialized to be able customize one of its style data.
For regular FMX objects there is a property 'StylesData' that allow such per-item customization before the view is initialized. But for TListViewItem, this property doesn't exist and there is no clear way to obtain a per-item customization when you create the said item. At least it's the case in today's Delphi XE 11.3.

The solution is to implement a **OnUpdateObjects** Event in the TListView component and during this event set any specific values that are needed for the style.

So your item creation code become:

```
procedure UpdateList(lv: TListView);
var
  Litem: TListViewItem;
  iName: TListItemText;
begin
  FDQuery.Open('SELECT Name, Value FROM tbl_values');

  lv.Items.Clear;
  lv.BeginUpdate;

  while not FDQuery.Eof do
  begin
    Litem := lv.Items.Add;

    iName      := Litem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Name');
    iName.Text := FDQuery.FieldValues['Name'];

    Litem.Tag  := FDQuery.FieldValues['Value']; 
    FDQuery.Next;
  end;

  lv.EndUpdate;
end;
```

and the OnUpdateObjects Event :

```
procedure TForm1.LVUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject; const aItem: TListViewItem);
var
  iAcc: TListItemAccessory;

begin
  if not assigned(aItem) then Exit;
  iAcc := aItem.Objects.AccessoryObject;
  if assigned(iAcc) then
  begin
    iAcc.Visible := aItem.Tag > 0;
  end;
end;
```

That's the only way I have found to do such per-item customization as of today.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
while not FDQuery.Eof do
  begin
    Litem := lv.Items.Add;
    
    **ListView1.ApplyStyleLookup;** //Add this line

    iName      := Litem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Name');
    iName.Text := FDQuery.FieldValues['Name'];

    iCheck     := LItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemAccessory>('Check');
    if FDQuery.FieldValues['Value'] > 0 then
      iCheck.Visible:= True
    else
      iCheck.Visible := False;

    FDQuery.Next;
  end;
```